# How to send mouse clicked coordinates from Flickable to ListView?

Tags: android, qt, qml

I'm developing an application for Android.

I have some ChartViews placed in the ListView.
Above ListView I have got a Flickable to scroll ChartViews synchronously in the x axis.

I need to show the coordinates of the point on the chart to which the user tap.

But I can't because flickable catches mouse click events and does not propagate it to other objects below.

I need the mouse event to come to a specific delegate that the user tapped on.
[image: it lookes like this]

1. Is it possible to solve this problem?
2. Is there a way to get mouse coordinates during flick?
3. Is there a way to propagate mouse events to the ListView as if they came from the user?

---

```
Rectangle {
color: "#ffffff"
Component {
    id: chartDelegate
    Rectangle {
        id: rootDelegRect

        anchors {left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
        height: 350

        ChartView {
            anchors { fill: parent;}
            x: -10
            y: -10
            width: parent.width + 20
            height: parent.height + 20

            legend.visible: false

            LineSeries {
                name: "LineSeries"
                axisX: ValueAxis {
                    min: 0
                    max: 4
                    labelFormat: "%.0f"
                }
                axisY: ValueAxis {
                    min: 0
                    max: 6
                    labelFormat: "%.0f"
                }
                XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0.0 }
                XYPoint { x: 1; y: 5.2 }
                XYPoint { x: 2; y: 2.4 }
                XYPoint { x: 3; y: 0.1 }
                XYPoint { x: 4; y: 5.1 }
            }
        }


        MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled :true
        onMouseXChanged: console.log(mouseX,mouseY);//does not work when clicked
        }
    }
}

ListView { id: listViewCharts; objectName: "chart";
    clip: true
    anchors.top: parent.top; anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;

    width: 1500

    contentX:baseFlick.contentX; contentY:baseFlick.contentY;

    model: listViewIdsModel
    cacheBuffer: 1500
    delegate: chartDelegate
}

Flickable {
    id: baseFlick
    anchors.fill: parent

    contentHeight: listViewCharts.contentHeight
    contentWidth:  listViewCharts.width

}
}
```

Comment: For what do you need `ListView`? This looks absolutely unnecessary. Just put `ChartView` inside `Flickable`.

Comment: I would like to use a ListView, because with each chart there will be additional information about each chart. In addition, the graphs receive data from the model that is already used in the project. I would like to use an object with a delegate. the number of graphs is not known in advance. And may change during operation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this problem can only be solved using c++

To capture Flickable mouse events, do the following:

1) add the objectName of the object is Flickable

```
objectName: "baseFlick"
```

2) in c++ after creating a qml scene. Find the baseFlick object and Installs an event filter on this object

```
auto rootObj = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
auto item = rootObj->findChild<QQuickItem *>("baseFlick");
if(item!=nullptr){
    item->installEventFilter(this);
} else qDebug()<<"ERR baseFlick item=nullptr";
```

3) implement the eventFilter virtual function

```
bool IDS2forUser::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    ...
    return false;
}
```

In order to propagate mouse events to the ListView as if they came from the user.
In the eventFilter function:

1) Find the ListView (chart) object

```
auto rootObj = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
auto item = rootObj->findChild<QQuickItem *>("chart");
```

2) Find all of his children.

You need to look for children every time as their number may change.

 Note, you should use the QQuickItem::childItems () function instead of QObject::children()

```
void IDS2forUser::getAllObjects(QQuickItem *parent, QList<QQuickItem *> &list) {

    QList<QQuickItem *> children = parent->childItems();
    foreach (QQuickItem *item, children) {
        list.append(item);
        getAllObjects(item,list);
    }
}
```

3) Convert all coordinates to local coordinates of the object. And send all children events.

The whole function is presented below.

```
bool IDS2forUser::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    auto rootObj = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
    auto item = rootObj->findChild<QQuickItem *>("chart");

    QList<QQuickItem *> list;
    getAllObjects(item, list);

    QQuickItem *watchedIt = dynamic_cast<QQuickItem *>(watched);
    if(!watchedIt)return false;

    QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
    if(!mouseEvent)return false;

    foreach (QQuickItem *item, list) {
        QPointF point=item->mapFromItem(watchedIt,mouseEvent->localPos());

        if(point.x()<0 || point.y()<0 || point.x()>=item->width() || point.y()>=item->height())continue;

        QMouseEvent mouseEvent2(mouseEvent->type(),
                                point,
                                mouseEvent->button(),mouseEvent->buttons(),Qt::NoModifier);
        QCoreApplication::sendEvent(item, &mouseEvent2);
   }
return false;
}
```